# Meteor.loginWithPassword() dont't check password and logins anyway

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

I have some code:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err) {
    if(err){
        notify.show(i18n.translate('Signin error'), i18n.translate(err.reason));
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

User logins anyway and no matter entered password or not. Error causes only if email is wrong or not found. The question is how to handle login validation on server?

UPD:

This is user document:

```
 db.users.findOne({'_id': "c53An5nTLGJ7zW35D"})
{
    "_id" : "c53An5nTLGJ7zW35D",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-03-05T12:13:24.853Z"),
    "emails" : [
        {
                "address" : "test@mail.com",
                "verified" : false
        }
    ],
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "srp" : {
                "identity" : "ijpCMGdM9z8kpnTeZ",
                "salt" : "HuEMd5Jyt8DCLWQKK",
                "verifier" : "b3e6c71650c449b4dcdd1d8ccb6cb472632307255c7b02efae9fd93032c2982de118d20be54d30d2af10741054bef4d54e4a8bced8064a37b9dd5390c5c5b3b84fbcb15fa8430a11d7792256d9d3de26cd1bcc1e37cf2b4e284667bcd1de4d28f1be7845b8689e4f22df024b7b4c8150a7133a68fa9374362a7feef97697c4f7"
            }
        },
        "resume" : {
                "loginTokens" : [ ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more details about the setup? That sounds wrong that it just signs you in without checking the password. Passwords are already validated on the server using SRP (so not sent in plaintext either), you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: What kind of setup details you need?

Comment: The values you use for `email`/`password` to log in and what is in your user document. You could use test values

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and very strange behavior with it. Accidentally i passed `$(template.find('#pass').value)` insted `$.trim(template.find('#pass').value)` and was signed in without errors.